# Computed height of an element set to display: none

Tags: javascript

To calculate a top position for an element of variable height, I was thinking of doing the following:

1. Move the element 1000px off the top of the viewport
2. Set the element to display: block
3. Get the height of the element
4. Set the element to display: none
5. Continue on as if everything is normal and good

Any pitfalls in this approach? Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look at [prototype's implementation](http://prototypejs.org/assets/2008/9/29/prototype-1.6.0.3.js) of `getDimensions`.

It sets the position to absolute, visibility to hidden, and display to block briefly. I've written one which handles getting the height of something which is contained within a `display:none` element, but it's a bit shonky in some edge cases.

Comment: That would get around having to move the element off the screen. It does mean I can set both properties in the same CSS call, rather than in sequence.

Comment: visibility=hide, and display:block is the way to go. I did something similar in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282758/truncate-a-string-nicely-to-fit-within-a-given-pixel-width#283994

Comment: I would suggest using position: fixed as absolute will be relative to elements using relative positioning (if you should happen to add it to a such). Also check out getBoundingClientRect() on the element.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just set the visibility to hidden and get the offsetHeight?

Comment: That looks like a viable technique, yes.