# How to crop a string which is exceeding the element length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html page I have tooltip. Some strings are not fitting correctly because of their length in the Tooltip image. But, I'mm not allowed to crop the string from server side.

I want to make the ToolTip to show first 8-12 chars and followed by dots.

Is there any inbuilt function available for it in javascript or jquery.

Thanks!

Comment: What decides whether it is 8 or 12 characters you want to display? Do you want to try to truncate at a word boundary if possible?

Comment: An answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282758/truncate-a-string-nicely-to-fit-within-a-given-pixel-width/283994#283994

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `string.substring(from, to)`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Then just append `"..."`

```
var x = "a really long line of text";
var toolTipText = x.substring(0, 8) + "...";
```

Comment: Not sure about the JavaScript `substring();` but in .NET if the string is only of length `< 8`, an exception would be thrown. I'd do a length check before the substring, just to be certain.

Comment: it works either way - no need to check.  but if it is shorter than 8 you shouldn't do this because then you will get the full text and `"..."`

Answer (score 12):

```
tip = tip.length > 12 ? tip.substring(0,12) + "..." : tip;
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the answers listed here (like using CSS3's text-overflow:ellipsis rule) are great if you just want to truncate a string, but they don't provide you with the ability to implement arbitrary logic like breaking on a whitespace or a hyphen.  Javascript provides that ability natively with the String#replace function.  Combined with regular expressions, this can support an amazingly powerful set of excerpting rules.  Here's how it works:

String#replace can take a function as its second parameter and handily passes in any regexp match and groupings as arguments, using the return value of the function to replace any match from the regexp.

Here's an example that will truncate and add an ellipsis to a string longer than 8 characters, but does nothing if the string is already shorter than that:

```
function replace_second_group_with_an_ellipsis(){
    return arguments[1] + (arguments[2] ? '...' : '');
}

toolTipString.replace(/(^.{0,8})(.*)/, replace_second_group_with_an_ellipsis);
```

The function passed as the second parameter to `replace()` will have an `arguments` object with the whole regexp match as its first value, and any further matching groups that you identified with parentheses in your regexp.

Of course, you can use any logic you like for replacement.  It might be nice to try to find the last whitespace to break on.  Unfortunately, there's no backreference in javascript regular expressions.  In this case, we could handle the backreference logic manually with a loop in our callback:

```
function shorten_nicely_with_ellipsis(){
    var str = arguments[1];
    var truncating = !!arguments[2];

    // If we're not already breaking on a whitespace character, loop
    // backwards over the string, and break on the first character of
    // the first group of whitespace characters we find. 
    if( truncating && !arguments[2].match(/^\s/) ) {
        for(var i=str.length; --i; i<=1) {
            if( str[i].match(/\s/) && !str[i-1].match(/\s/) ) {
                str = arguments[1].substr(0, i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if( truncating ) {                
        str = str + '...';
    }

    return str;
}


toolTipString.replace(/(^.{0,8})(.*)/, shorten_nicely_with_ellipsis);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use a regular expression as given below since I need not care for the string length and manipulation:

```
var regExp = /(.{8})(.*)/;
<YOUR_INPUT_STRING>.replace(regExp, "$1...");
 //e.g. "It is a very big string I donno why it is so big.".replace(regExp, "$1...");
```

Answer (score 2):

Not actually JavaScript (and not universally available), but the CSS `text-overflow: ellipsis` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 introduces `text-overflow: ellipsis`, which is exactly what you're looking for.  [Here](http://deepubalan.com/blog/2010/11/27/text-overflow-css3-property-explained-pure-css-solution-to-get-ellipsis/) is an article on it, including how to make it work in firefox, which doesn't support the property yet.